# Pandas Resampling OHLC intraday data excluding outside regular trading hours

Tags: pandas

I'm resampling 30 min data to hourly data but its adding NaN rows representing all 30 mins periods over a 24 hour period.  I would like it to resample only if there is data in the 30 min record.  The original df does not have any 'extra' rows and just hourly data from 9:30-4:00 over 20 days. Also its including weekends in the new df_RSHourly.

```
df_RSHourly = df.resample('1H', base=0.5).agg(
    {'close': 'last','high': 'max','low': 'min', 'open': 'first', 'volume': 'sum'}
]

print df_RSHhourly
```

```
2017-04-25 09:30:00-04:00  238.75  238.52  237.91  237.81  151998.0
2017-04-25 10:30:00-04:00  238.62  238.44  238.53  238.33   64281.0
2017-04-25 11:30:00-04:00  238.66  238.56  238.44  238.36   58319.0
2017-04-25 12:30:00-04:00  238.71  238.59  238.56  238.29   47994.0
2017-04-25 13:30:00-04:00  238.82  238.69  238.59  238.52   58266.0
2017-04-25 14:30:00-04:00  238.95  238.84  238.69  238.57   73089.0
2017-04-25 15:30:00-04:00  238.83  238.53  238.83  238.53  103572.0
2017-04-25 16:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 17:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 18:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 19:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 20:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 21:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 22:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-25 23:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 00:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 01:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 02:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 03:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 04:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 05:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 06:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 07:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 08:30:00-04:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN
2017-04-26 09:30:00-04:00  238.91  238.87  238.53  238.50   91978.0
2017-04-26 10:30:00-04:00  239.53  239.47  238.88  238.85   75444.0
2017-04-26 11:30:00-04:00  239.48  239.02  239.48  238.70   88402.0
2017-04-26 12:30:00-04:00  239.42  239.20  239.02  238.98   45661.0
```

Comment: I think you can just use `dropna`... `df_RSHhourly.dropna()`

Comment: I don't think that will resample correctly if i do it after the df is created. Will it?  Because the data from 4:00 to 9:30 won't be resampled correct to build the correct hourly bar?  I want it to resample without creating the NaN row values to begin with if that is possible. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with minutes resampling, I found 2 way to solve it

## The simple but inefficient way

I initially solved it by adding a utility column that checks whether the date/time should be included and then I take the slice where the condition is True

```
def in_hours(row):
    if row.name.hour >= 22 
       or row.name.hour < 9 
       or row.name.hour == 9 and row.name.minute < 30:
        return False
    return True

df['keep'] = df.apply(in_hours, axis=1)
df2 = dft[dft['keep']==True]
del dft['keep']
```

I don't find this particularly elegant or efficient since that could lead resampling to generate a lot of useless data only to be discarded later but I could not find a smarter way.
Also note that additional logic is required in "in_hours" if the market closes early!

## A more reliable way

I take daily slices resample between daily boundaries and then concatenate daily dataframe, it is more memory and computation intensive but more reliable

```
#create a colume with the day for grouping by
df['day'] = df.index
#group by day and get the max time, ie time of the last data of the day
df2 = df.day.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).max()
resampled_df_list = []

#for each day resample
for max_time in df2:
    if type(max_time) is pd.tslib.Timestamp: # will be NaT on WE
        end_time = max_time
        start_time = datetime(max_time.year, max_time.month, 
max_time.day, 0, 0)
        df1d = df.loc[start_time:end_time].resample('1min').mean()
        resampled_df_list.append(df1d)

#put it back together
new_df = pd.concat(resampled_df_list)
```

Comment: What if there are gaps in your data (ie no trades in that 30 mins or perhaps in a whole hour for an non-liquid security)

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution I found was `between_time`

```
df_RSHhourly.between_time('09:30', '16:00')
```

In my code, this is how I applied it:

```
y = data['prices'].resample('60S').ohlc()
y = y.fillna(method='ffill')
y = y.between_time('09:30', '16:00')
```

Reference:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: What would be the full solution here?  Execute the resampling and then apply the between_tiem function?  df_RSHourly = df.resample('1H', base=0.5).agg(
    {'close': 'last','high': 'max','low': 'min', 'open': 'first', 'volume': 'sum'}
]  then df_RSHhourly.between_time('09:30', '16:00')